# httpClient slow to send data

Tags: tcp, httpclient, tcpdump

I use java `HttpClient 4.3.5` to send a file, I create HttpClient with this config

```java
SocketConfig soConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
            .setTcpNoDelay(true)
            .build();
    int socketSendBufferSizeHint = config.getSocketSendBufferSizeHint();
    int socketReceiveBufferSizeHint = config.getSocketReceiveBufferSizeHint();
    int buffersize = 0;
    if (socketSendBufferSizeHint > 0 || socketReceiveBufferSizeHint > 0) {
        buffersize = Math.max(socketSendBufferSizeHint, socketReceiveBufferSizeHint);
    }
    ConnectionConfig coConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
            .setBufferSize(buffersize)
            .build();
    RequestConfig reConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(config.getConnectionTimeOut())
            .setSocketTimeout(config.getSocketTimeOut())
            .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

and use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` connection manager,
when I use `response = client.execute(httpRequest);` to send a http request. But the client send data 1MB data may cost 720ms per request. Under normal circumstances,only 75ms is needed, I use tcpdump get data below. I don't understand why java http client send data slower than python. any help, thanks.

```

```java
22:20:13.800409 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [.], seq 2566415:2575079, ack 733, win 1452, length 8664
22:20:13.800427 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [.], seq 2575079:2582299, ack 733, win 1452, length 7220
22:20:13.800673 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2569303, win 6137, length 0
22:20:13.800678 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [P.], seq 2582299:2582828, ack 733, win 1452, length 529
22:20:13.800797 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2582299, win 6123, length 0
22:20:13.809401 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [.], seq 2582828:2590048, ack 733, win 1452, length 7220
22:20:13.809411 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [.], seq 2590048:2597268, ack 733, win 1452, length 7220
22:20:13.809665 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2585716, win 6137, length 0
22:20:13.809673 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [P.], seq 2597268:2599241, ack 733, win 1452, length 1973
22:20:13.809790 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2597268, win 6137, length 0
22:20:13.809920 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2599241, win 6137, length 0
22:20:13.818367 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [.], seq 2599241:2606461, ack 733, win 1452, length 7220
22:20:13.818376 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [.], seq 2606461:2613681, ack 733, win 1452, length 7220
22:20:13.818385 IP tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759 > 198.18.96.40.https: Flags [P.], seq 2613681:2615654, ack 733, win 1452, length 1973
22:20:13.818639 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2602129, win 6137, length 0
22:20:13.822745 IP 198.18.96.40.https > tj1-smart-camera-mt00.kscn.24759: Flags [.], ack 2615654, win 6137, length 0
```

```

Comment: You not only failed to ask a question, but you haven't given us any code to look at, only packets.  There's absolutely nothing that we can tell from these.

Comment: I hava re-edit my question, thanks